# How to traverse a GitHub repository artifacts (commits, PRs, issues) in chronological order?

Tags: git, github

Planning to do some software archaeology in a [fairly large repo](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) to dig up long lost rationale for design decisions (if any). I presume that my best bet is to use [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) to get all the artifacts needed, then process and correlate them by date in some way.

What would be a better method? Are there any existing projects that cover this area? Couldn't find much with google.

---

**edit**:

- > I usually browse the history in gitk, or magit in Emacs. –
  > choroba

  I completely forgot that there is also [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) for Vim which will serve great for some "preliminary digging" (but looking at magit wants me to give emacs a try, thanks:)
- > Worth mentioning: GitHub create issues and PRs with a simple master index number that increments by 1 each time. So you can just plow linearly through items by their number. That won't help you correlate with commits though, at least not directly. –
  > torek

  Thank you for confirming this! I was playing around in GitHub's web UI, and found it interesting that when clicking on the Issues tab and removing the predefined query (i.e., `is:issue is:open`), the resulting list shows both PRs and issues together in chronological order.

Comment: I usually browse the history in `gitk`, or `magit` in Emacs.

Comment: @choroba: that only works for commits; PRs and issues on GitHub are in a separate database that can only be accessed from GitHub itself. (But it's fine for commits!)

Comment: Worth mentioning: GitHub create issues and PRs with a simple master index number that increments by 1 each time. So you can just plow linearly through items by their number. That won't help you correlate with commits though, at least not directly.